# how to get basic block ID of a statement inside visit* methods

Tags: clang, static-analysis, llvm-clang

How can we get basic block id (blockID) of a statement when we override 
visit* methods?

e.g. for a basic block given below, when VisitIfStmt() is visited, how 
to get blockID inside this visit method?
      [B4]
        1: x == 0
        T: if [B4.1]
        Preds (1): B6
        Succs (2): B3 B2

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had to answer the same lately. You can use the [`CFGStmtMap`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CFGStmtMap.html) to query for the BBL of a statement:

```cpp
const FunctionDecl* FD = ...;
const CFG* cfg = ...;
std::unique_ptr<ParentMap> PM = llvm::make_unique<ParentMap>(FD->getBody());
std::unique_ptr<CFGStmtMap> CM = llvm::make_unique<CFGStmtMap>(cfg, PM.get());
// do your traversal and for a given Stmt `stmt` you can get
// its containing block:
CFGBlock* stmt_block = CM->getBlock(stmt);
const unsigned int block_id = stmt_block->getBlockID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use llvm::PHINode::getBasicBlockIndex ( const BasicBlock *BB).